# access multiple ng-model in one directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a form which needs to be accessed in the directive

```
<form name="itemForm">
<span ng-repeat="item in items">
<ng-form name="itemsForm">

<input type="radio" name="portfolioType" ng-model="item.type" value="TEXT"/>
<input type="radio" name="portfolioType" ng-model="item.type" value="VIDEO"/>

<input type="text" id="title" name="title" ng-model="item.title" required />
<input type="text" id="name" name="title" ng-model="item.name" required />
<input type="text" id="description" name="title" ng-model="item.description" required />

</ng-form>
</span>
</form>
```

I want to access all the ng-models in directive so I can do some validations. This form is dynamic. Input fields can be added by user dynamically.